# How to check if Nikkor lens has IF feature?

Tags: lens, nikon, internal-focus

The specification for the [lens](http://www.nikonusa.com/Nikon-Products/Product/Camera-Lenses/2179/AF-S-DX-NIKKOR-18-105mm-f%252F3.5-5.6G-ED-VR.html#tab-ProductDetail-ProductTabs-TechSpecs) says that the **Nikkor 18-105mm ED VR** has the IF feature. However, the local market product label doesn't advertise this feature. How can I make sure that the IF feature is there? Is it possible that Nikon has the same lens with and without the IF feature?

Strange enough Nikon itself does not advertise the IF feature in the product label as I would usually see (IF-ED).

Comment: This is a fairly recent DX lens, so it's highly unlikely there are two versions of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "IF" is included on the lens (see image here on Ken Rockwell's site): [18-105mm specifications](http://www.kenrockwell.com/nikon/18-105mm.htm#spex)

The lens will extend when you zoom.  IF (in this instance) appears only to mean that once you set a focal point, say 105mm, as you *focus* the outer part of the lens won't move.  So if you have a polarising filter on, it won't turn as you focus.

Edit: just read the PHotozone review which basically says what I said above. Lens will extend as you zoom, but not rotate as you focus.  Quite different than lenses which do not extend/rotate as they zoom OR focus.

Comment: Both Stack Exchange and Imgur terms suggest against uploading images where copyright belongs to somebody else, [more details on Meta](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/295/do-photos-uploaded-here-have-to-be-cc-wiki-too).

Comment: Thanks, read the link on Meta, not really sure what to make of it. Will edit to just have a link to that page rather than using the image.  I would imagine he'd be happy to have an attributed image, but a link drives actual traffic over to his site, so that might be a better option.

Answer (score 0):

The [Photozone review](http://www.photozone.de/Reviews/410-nikkor_18105_3556vr) of the lens also notes that it has internal focussing, so you can take that as further indication, however the easiest way to be sure is to go into the store and try it.

Comment: That's what I read too before posting. But if I go to store, how exactly to check IF feature with D7000 body?

Comment: @Pablo - Ask to try it, they probably have a demo model available for you. I suppose places can vary, but I've never had a problem trying out a lens in a store.

Comment: The point of questions seems to be _how can you tell that a lens has IF_.

Comment: IF means all the elements that move during focusing are internal, so the outer shell of the lens doesn't rotate or extend.  You can either observe it visually, or actually hold the outside edge of the lens, where the lens cap would attach, and see/feel if it moves when you focus.